# database schema for timesheet

Tags: database-design, schema, database-schema

Could someone help me with a rough database schema for a timesheet application where the i would be able to

1. Store hours per day for a time period ( 2 weeks ) for different projects. Ex person A can put 3 hours for projectA and 4 hours for projectB on the same day
2. Make it so that its is easy to get a reports on total hours put for a project, or to get total hours on all projects by a certain person

EDIT: Another requirement would be that each timesheet for a particular time period for every person needs to have a field indicating that the person has submitted the timesheet and another saying that it has been approved

Comment: YOU can;t do just submitted and approved, you need a returned process. Otherwise there is no point to an approval process. YOu cannto design a timesheet application without extensive knowldge of legal requirements, contract requirements, internal controls, timesheet fraud and how to prevent it and auditing. All of these are critical to the design of a timesheet application. It is better to buy one from someone who has done the legal research needed that to grow your own and create more problems than you can imagine right now.

Comment: @HLGEM You could say that potentially about any off the shelf software and just get away from touching code. You could create a concept application and work through the issues and learn along the way. You learn more from problems than anything else.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Borrowing from Eric Petroelje & mdma:

```
Employee 
- EmployeeID (PK)
- EmployeeName
- Other_fields

Project
- ProjectID (PK)
- ProjectName
- Other_fields

WorkSegment
- WorkSegmentID (PK)
- ProjectID (IX1)
- EmployeeID (IX2)
- Date (IX1, IX2)
- StartTime 
- EndTime
- PayrollCycleID (FK)
```

The first index of WorkSegment is ProjectID, Date.  The second index of WorkSegment is EmployeeID, Date.  These indexes are not unique.  This is so a person can work on a project more than once in one day.  The indexes allow for reporting on hours worked by project or by person.

Each WorkSegment row is for one segment of time, one day, one project.  Each employee has as many WorkSegment rows as is needed to describe his payroll cycle.

```
TimeSheetSegment
- TimeSheetSegmentID (PK)
- ProjectId (FK)
- EmployeeId (FK)
- PayrollCycleID (FK)
```

There is a unique index on ProjectID, EmployeeID, and PayrollCycleID.  There is one TimeSheetSegment row for each project that an employee works for during a payroll cycle.

```
TimeSheet
- TimeSheetID (PK)
- EmployeeID (IX)
- PayrollCycleID (IX)
```

The TimeSheet row brings the TimeSheetSegment and WorkSegment rows together.  The EmployeeID, PayrollCycleID index is unique.

```
Approval
- TimeSheetID (PK)
- PayrollCycleID (FK)
- SubmittedTimestamp
- ApproverID (FK)
- ApprovedTimestamp
```

The Approval row is created when the time sheet is submitted.  These fields could be part of the TimeSheet table.  I broke them out with a fourth-order normalization because the Approval table is likely to have different database access permissions than the TimeSheet table.

```
PayrollCycle
- PayrollCycleID (PK)
- PayrollCycleYear
- PayrollCycleNumber
- StartDate 
- EndDate
- DirectDepositDate
- CheckDate
- Other_fields
```

The PayrollCycle table normalizes some of the date fields, and provides an integer key that makes it easier to pull together the WorkSegment and TimeSheetSegment rows to make a coherent time sheet.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a rough sketch that will give you a good start:

```
Project
-------
ProjectId  PK
ProjectName varchar(200)

Employee
---------
EmployeeId  PK
EmployeeName (or first name/last name etc..)
// .. other employee attributes


ProjectTimesheet
----------------
ProjectTimesheetId PK
ProjectId          FK -> Project.ProjectId
EmployeeId         FK -> Employee.EmployeeId
StartTime          DATETIME
EndTime            DATETIME
Approved           bit
```

EDIT: As an alternative to the approved flag in each ProjectTimesheet row, you could instead separate out the approved status to a separate table. For example, to allow approval for an employee's timesheet over a given period, a manager would add an approval entry to the Approval table:

```
Approval
--------
ApprovalID    PK
EmployeeId    FK -> Employee.EmployeeId
StartTime     DATETIME
EndTime       DATETIME
ApprovedBy    FK -> Employee.EmployeeId (e.g. the manager)
ApprovedDate  timestamp  // date the approval was registered
```

Comment: and how would I indicate for a particular timesheet for a person that it has been submitted by that person ?

Comment: You can add an approved flag to the ProjectTimesheet table to indicate it has been approved. The process is, timesheet is submitted - approved==0. Timesheet approved by manager: approved==1.

Comment: but I need to keep track of hours for individual days. Is one row in the ProjectTimesheet for one period ( 2 weeks ) or for individual days? If it is for days, I would have to update 14 rows for the Approved column every time a person submits the timesheet

Comment: Sorry, I meant to explain a little more, but got distracted. Each row in the ProjectTimesheet is for a single project worked on. StartTime/EndTime are assumed to be on the same day, so a project worked on over multiple days includes multiple rows. Yes, approving a 2 week period will involve updating 14 rows. The alternative is to separate out Approved to a separate table, which I've added as an edit.

Comment: @TP - best to just update all 14 rows rather than having a separate Approval table.  Updating 14 rows is no big deal - databases are designed for that kind of stuff.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds a bit like homework, but I'd probably start with something like this:

```
People 
  - PersonID (PK)
  - PersonName
  - Other fields

Projects
  - ProjectID (PK)
  - ProjectName
  - Other fields

WorkTime
  - TimeID (PK)
  - ProjectID (FK)
  - PersonID (FK)
  - StartTime
  - EndTime
```

Comment: and how would I indicate for a particular timesheet for a person that it has been submitted by that person ? I would not be able to do it in the WorkTime table.

Comment: @TP - If not that person, who else would be submitting it?  PersonID is on the WorkTime table already.

Comment: what I mean is that the person can fill it out but has to submit it for approval.

Comment: @TP - Then you would just add a "Submitted" field to the WorkTime table along with an "Approved" field (as others have suggested)

Answer (score 0):

A table for people(1)

A table for projects(2)

A table for bookings(3) - who did the work (FK into 1), what project did they work on (FK into 2), when did they do the work, how much work did they do.

Select sum(time_booked) from (3) where person equals (some id from 1) and project = (some ID from 2)

or

Select sum(time_booked) from (3) where person equals (some id from 1)

etc...

Answer (score 0):

The following code is taken from the []project-open[](http://www.project-open.com) open-source system in PostgreSQL syntax and edited.

Please note the "conf_objects" table with approval/confirmation information. When the user "submits" a time sheet, all submitted hours are assigned to a new conf_object. It's the job of the supervisor to set the status of the conf_object to "approved". Both the supervisor or the user may delete the conf_object at any time, which will will mark the hours as "not submitted" (hour.conf_object_id = NULL) again, so that these hours will end up on the "Hours Not Submitted" report.

```
CREATE TABLE projects (
    project_id                      integer constraint projects_pk primary key,
    project_name                    text not null,
    parent_id                       integer constraint projects_parent_fk references projects,
[...]
    project_type_id                 integer not null constraint projects_prj_type_fk references categories,
    project_status_id               integer not null constraint projects_prj_status_fk references categories,
    description                     text,
    start_date                      timestamptz,
    end_date                        timestamptz
);


CREATE TABLE users (
    user_id integer constraint users_pk primary key,
    first_names text,
    last_name text
[...]
);

-- Confirmation (=approval) objects
CREATE TABLE conf_objects (
    conf_id         integer constraint conf_id_pk primary key,
    conf_status_id  integer constraint conf_status_nn not null
);


CREATE TABLE hours (
    user_id                 integer constraint hours_user_id_nn not null constraint hours_user_id_fk references users,
    project_id              integer constraint hours_project_id_nn not null constraint hours_project_id_fk references projects,
    day                     date constraint hours_day_nn not null,
    hours                   numeric(5,2) not null,
[...]
    note                    text,
    conf_object_id          integer constraint hours_conf_object_fk references conf_objects
);
```

The original ]po[ SQL statements are included in the ~/packages/intranet-*/sql/postgresql/intranet-*-create.sql creation scripts.